# Python Dictionary - If Key is Same, Create a List of Corresponding Values (String Data Type)

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, data-wrangling

I have a data type that looks like this:

```
{'name': 'brian', 'location': 'Brookings, OR'}
{'name': 'brian', 'location': 'Medford, OR'}
{'name': 'tommy', 'location': 'Portland, OR'}
{'name': 'tommy', 'location': 'Medford, OR'}
{'name': 'tommy', 'location': 'Oklahoma City, OK'}
```

What I would like to do is if the Key (name) is the same, then I create a list of corresponding values like so:

```
{'name': 'brian', 'location': ['Brookings, OR', 'Medford, OR']}
{'name': 'tommy', 'location': ['Portland, OR', 'Medford, OR', 'Oklahoma City, OK']}
```

I've done this with integer data types by adding the values together is the key was the same, but I can't get my head around this. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Considering as l the list that includes your dictionaries:

```
l=[{'name': 'brian', 'location': 'Brookings, OR'},
{'name': 'brian', 'location': 'Medford, OR'},
{'name': 'tommy', 'location': 'Portland, OR'},
{'name': 'tommy', 'location': 'Medford, OR'},
{'name': 'tommy', 'location': 'Oklahoma City, OK'}]
```

you can do the following:

```
res=[{'name':i, 'location':[k['location'] for k in l if k['name']==i]} for i in set([p['name'] for p in l])]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print(res)

[{'name': 'brian', 'location': ['Brookings, OR', 'Medford, OR']}, {'name': 'tommy', 'location': ['Portland, OR', 'Medford, OR', 'Oklahoma City, OK']}]
```

Comment: this is an inefficient way of doing this. Better to use the normal grouping idiom